# How can devise allowing me to update password without passing current password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the rails 3.2.x with devise to authenticate the user password.
On one page I am updating allowing user to update the his password. But even after providing the wrong current password, user can be able to update his/her password.

Same thing is happening with the rails console.

```
@user = user.update_attributes :password => "some_password"
```

updates the @user's password.

How to get away with this trouble?

**UPDATE**:
I can update user password with wrong current_password parameter to update_attributes method like,

```
@user = user.update_attributes :password => "some_password", :current_password => "wrong_password"
```

Comment: What is your question. Should the user be allowed to update his password without giving the current password ?

Comment: No, user should not be allowed to update his password without providing the correct current_password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out,

instead of using

```
 user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

one can use

```
user.update_with_password(params[:user])
```

This will insure that current password is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need use

`before_filter :authenticate_user!`

Comment: thanks for your time, but problem is not about authenticating the current user, but updating the password with correct current password. But time being devise allowing user to update password without passing current_password to update_attributes method.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add `:password => "some_password"` and `:confirm_password => "some_password"`
or you have to add in controller `:before_filter => authenticate_user!.`

Comment: thanks for your time Sumit, but I devise is allowing me to update the password with wrong current_user parameter to update_attributes method.

Comment: @Sush, Have you mention in your routes.rb the devise_for loop contains **get 'changepassword' => 'devise/registrations#edit'** it may be helpful to you.